# Why would there be 2 inputs of the same type on a display?

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport

I'm looking to get a new set of displays, and on an Amazon listing I saw the following in a review:

> Only one DisplayPort. Instead of 2 HDMI ports, I would have preferred 2 DisplayPorts and 1 HDMI.

Why would you need more than one of any port at a given time? I have not seen a display with 2 inputs of the same type. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its so that you can switch between multiple devices, For instance 1 port uses your computer while the other uses your playstation. By changing the input you can flip from computer to playstation without doing anything cable related.

Comment: That was the only explanation I had as well, but I was not sure if there was more to it.

Comment: @jeff other than that it does nothing. You cant have them display both at the same time. It works just like a tv